# How to write a Choose function in powershell to edit the pipeline?

Tags: powershell, editor, pipeline

I wish to edit the git [sparse-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) information *inplace* using the [nvim](https://neovim.io/) editor. I have the following code that almost works.

```
function Choose () {
    begin {
        $file = New-TemporaryFile
    }
    process 
    {
        $_ >> $file
    }
    end {
        nvim $file
        Get-Content $file
        Remove-Item $file 
    }
}

function Git-Sparse-Checkout-Edit 
{
    git sparse-checkout list | Choose | git sparse-checkout set --stdin

}
```

if I write

```
git sparse-checkout list | Choose
```

then the nvim editor is opened on the output of the git sparse-checkout command and when I 'wq' ( save and quit ) then the contents of the file are written to stdout. But when I try

```
git sparse-checkout list | Choose | git sparse-checkout set --stdin
```

instead of opening the editor the entire windows terminal stalls and I have to kill it. Is my Choose function correctly implemented?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Choose () {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]]
        $Text
    )
    begin {
        $file = New-TemporaryFile
        $Text
    }
    process 
    {
        foreach ($line in $Text){
            $line >> $file
        }
    }
    end{
        start-process nvim $file -wait
        Get-Content $file
        Remove-Item $file 
    }
}
```

and using it to edit the git sparse-checkout list

```
function Git-Sparse-Checkout-Edit 
{
    git sparse-checkout list | Choose | git sparse-checkout set --stdin

}
```

Using [start-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2) seems to be the key to stop the pipeline stalling though I'm not sure why.